When unwrapping a UV map, how do I make the UV nodes connect to eachother instead of being many separate islands?

Here's and example of what I want to do, some parts of the object are their own separate islands, while some are connected, like the large one in the right corner is symmetrical. Any help is appreciated.

Hello, you need to create some UV seams then press U > Unwrap and choose one of the 3 first options, the islands will only separate depending on the seams

@moonboots Could you give an example on how to? Thanks.

in Edit mode, select the edges where you want the seperations to happen and press U > Mark Seam, then select all and U > Unwrap > choose one of the 3 first options
